# Why do some HTTPS sites simply refuse a connection?

Tags: ssl, https, connection, esp8266

Good afternoon, Stackies! I'm developing an asynchronous C++ HTTP/S library for ESP8266 / ESP32 and I'm having some problems with TLS as I'm pretty new to it. I have a vague idea of what the problem is, but no clue as to how to fix it or even gather more info on it. Your collective advice is respectfully requested.

My firmware layer cake is:

1. Arduino core 2.7.4
2. LwIP 2
3. ESPAsyncTCP lib (my own patched version, the original has fatal bugs :( )
4. Let's call it "mylib"

Good news is that thus far I can successfully connect to some sites over TLS and get back meaningful data.

The problem is that some other sites simply refuse the connection. Now I'm pretty sure its because ESPAsyncTCP is using an ancient version of TLS and the combined fw stack described above has only cheap and cheezy and probably easily hackable ciphers available.

My problem is:

1. I cannot Wireshark the txn as its coming out over WiFi and I don't have a promiscuous capable WiFi adapter (I THINK this is my problem, bottom line is: I can't see the traffic on my dev machine). I have a  "normal" router (ie not any linux-y thing I can log into and run tcpdump or anything fancy like that)
2. I wouldn't understand the handshake / cipher exchange even if I COULD see it

Relevant facts:

1. ALL of the sites give me valid responses from my dev PC out through the same router, i.e. I don't think it's a firewall or port-blocking issue at the border
2. The site that DO allow connection from mylib on ESP8266 all return exactly the same output a they do to my dev PC, kinda reinforcing my view that it's not FW-based, but remote site-specific.

What I *think* is happening is that the remote site starts the TLS handshaking, sees the the client's best offer of encryption is outdated / insecure / not good enough in some other way (as I said, I'm really light on TLS knowledge / jargon) and saves everyone the bother by not even connecting.

What I need is some way a) to confirm my theory b) discover the real reason and get round it if not a)

My future plans are to add some stronger encryption with a better ssl lib than the axtls that ESPAsyncTCP uses, such as e.g. BearSSL that now comes as standard with ESP cores...but I'm not looking foward to that and it won't happen quickly. In the meanwhile I'd like to be able to offer something that at least works on some sites, but at least give an explanation of why / how it won't with others etc.

FYI, here are some that DO work:

1. My own Windows IIS with a self-generated certificate
2. https://restcountries-v1.p.rapidapi.com (using my own api key(s))
3. https://clienttest.ssllabs.com:8443/ssltest/viewMyClient.html
   (sslabs returns only a ton of headers and zero length body...so not a lot of help - I cant find a plaintext or JSON api endpoint)

And a few that don't

1. https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check (I was hoping THIS would give me the answers to this question!)
2. https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
3. https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2

I lack sufficient knowledge to discover what the "bad" ones have in common, and how that makes them behave differently from the "good" ones... HELP!

Comment: hackers on open wifi-networks use arp spoofing to divert traffic from legitimate gateway to theirs devices to do mitm stuff. In you setup you are the boss so you can skip all the trickery and configure your DUT to use your workstation as a gateway. Then you will be able to use wireshark even without having any wifi adapter in your workstation.

Comment: Only if I can put my cheap adapter into AP mode... which I can't :(

Comment: you do not need wifi adapter at all for the setup I'm suggesting to you. when you configure your esp device you either specify dhcp mode or use static ip address along with ip address of your router. if you configure esp device to use your workstation as a gateway then wifi frames from esp will go to the router but router will forward ethernet frames to your workstation via ethernet cable instead of passing them to the WAN interface. And you just need to configure your workstation to forward frames back to the router. this way you will be able to sniff all traffic of your esp device.

Comment: OK, it's getting complex, but..." you just need to configure your workstation to forward frames back to the router" any nice easy suggestions on how to do that on Windows10 box?

Comment: ESP32/ESP8288 device has added some CAs to trusted list. Check whether the site you are connecting to has SSL cert issued by CA in your trusted list. If not, you may have to add the server issuing CA to your device trusted list. The other possibility is that if your device and your server in the same LAN (normally for development env), your device won't be able to connect to HTTPS server